# AngularJS hide table when table has no rows

Tags: angularjs, html-table

How can I conditionally hide a HTML table, when the table has no rows? As I am using filters, I do not know beforehand if the result set will be empty or not.

I am iterating over the table rows, but the outer table (including the thead) will get rendered, even if there are no rows. How can I introspect into the length of the resulting array and use that information for ng-show / ng-hide?

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change class depending on filter result in AngularJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20687586/how-to-change-class-depending-on-filter-result-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are some possible solutions, but the best one would depend on your requirements and restrictions. If it's not a huge application, and you don't expect to have too many items in your unfiltered array, the best solution would be probably to simply use a `ng-show` with the same filter:

```html
<table ng-show="(items | filter:criteria).length">
  <tr ng-repeat="item in items | filter:criteria">...</tr>
</table>
```

But keep in mind that your filter will run through all items of the array twice, on every digest cycle. And if performance might be a problem, then you probably want your controller to digest this value for you and just bind it to your scope:

```js
controller('YourCtrl', function($scope, $filter) {
  // $watchCollection available in version 1.1+
  $scope.$watchCollection('items', function(newVal) {
    $scope.filteredItems = $filter('filter')(newVal, $scope.criteria);
  });
});
```

And in your HTML:

```js
<table ng-show="filteredItems.length">
  <tr ng-repeat="item in filteredItems">...</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is a good answer, specifically the suggestion about doing the filtering in the controller.

Comment: I put my controller here http://jsfiddle.net/jaL6b/1/ and included your solution. But the watchcollection doesn't get called. Using angular 1.2.6

Comment: Ok, another try. See http://jsfiddle.net/jaL6b/2/ : I now register the filter function properly and it get's called. The only strange thing I notice is, that the filter function get's called for every item in the collection, instead of the whole collection. I thought that this filter function is supposed to return the filtered array.

Comment: The fiddles are not working, they have invalid JS code, maybe you changed it?

Comment: @CaioToOn I am having difficulties in creating a MWE, the stuff is just to new (for me). But the filter receives only one element instead of the array. As such it can not return (and set) the array as you suggested.

Comment: @CaioToOn entirely my fault, array is nested in newVal, had to pass correct reference to filter function. Works perfectly!