# How to show a message when filter returns nothing in ng-repeat - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I would like to show one div(message) when no items returned on filter(ng-repeat).

Filter is happening based on select box (ng-model). And there are no results for some select options, at that time user should be able to read a message at same place.
Can I use ng-show/hide here? How?

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change class depending on filter result in AngularJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20687586/how-to-change-class-depending-on-filter-result-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can also save your filtered array in a variable and then use that variable inside the `ng-show` expression:

```
<select ng-model="shade" ng-options="shade for shade in shades"></select><br>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="c in filteredColors = (colors | filter:shade)">{{c.name}}</li>
</ul>
<div ng-show="!filteredColors.length">No colors available</div>
```

You can see it in action in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OiOtqa?p=preview).

Comment: This message no colors available, is showing while loading data, how to prevent that from NOT showing that message while loading?

Comment: @SudarshanKalebere you can have a flag to know whether the data is being loaded.

Answer (score 13):

You can get the size of array returned by filter using something like

`{{(data|filter:query).length}}`

You can use this expression for `ng-show` expression. I am not sure how performant would it be.

Comment: this way is better then custom filter, shorter and integrated with ngShow/hide

Comment: Not great for performance i assume. You do get the intended result but are  unnecessarily running the filter again just to calculate its length.

Comment: Performance hit. I agree with Nathvarun. I prefer the solution suggested by muenchdo

Answer (score 8):

There's a simpler solution using just the standard syntax of ngRepeat.

As stated in the [official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat), the ngRepeat accepts an alias for the collection even if filter are applied to it:

```
<div ng-repeat="model in collection | filter:search | orderBy: 'id' as filtered_result track by model.id">
    {{model.name}}
</div>
```

**Note**: I added ad additional filter to the example copied from the documentation to have a more complete example.

In this example you can simply use:

```
<div class="alert alert-info" 
     ng-show="filtered_result.length == 0">
    No items in the collection!
</div>
```

I tested it with AngularJS 1.5.0, I can't tell when this feature was introduced.