# AngularJS - how to show count 0 when ng-repeat and filter returns no rows

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to print the count of elements filtered through a condition in AngularJS.
I am using `ng-repeat` to loop over collection and filter it to get counts and it works fine when there is value in it. However, when the filter returns empty result, Angular doesn't render the element and hence, I can't get it to display 0 count.
http://plnkr.co/edit/KNVwf2Yckxf1Qcyzcmea?p=preview

```
<div ng-repeat="i in iArr|filter:i.name='tim'">{{i.vals.length}}</div>
```

Does anyone have a clue to make it work in simple fashion.

Edit:
The question [How to show a message when filter returns nothing in ng-repeat - AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21524572/how-to-show-a-message-when-filter-returns-nothing-in-ng-repeat-angularjs) has a reply which actually solved my question but I don't know how. I am wondering if there is a very simple way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

From that answer:

```
<select ng-model="shade" ng-options="shade for shade in shades"></select><br>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="c in filteredColors = (colors | filter:shade)">{{c.name}}</li>
</ul>
<div ng-show="!filteredColors.length">No colors available</div>
```

The key is in `c in filteredColors = (colors | filter:shade)`. The array result of the filter expression `colors | filter:shade` is being set to filteredColors, which then becomes available on the `$scope` object. Because of this, it can be used elsewhere in that controller scope. This is why it can be checked for its length to see if there are no colors.

Comment: Whoa, that was quick! thanks for the reply.
i was able to understand that much myself. i am looking to understanding how does that statement get interpreted like, why does that create global variable for that scope as opposed to when i tried with ng-model which didnt work.
and ***my question is about a simpler way to accomplish what i want to do, if any.***
for now, this is what works

     <div ng-repeat="i in i2=(iArr|filter:i.name=srch)">{{i.vals.length}}</div>

    {{i2.length==0?'0':''}}

updated plunker link http://plnkr.co/edit/KNVwf2Yckxf1Qcyzcmea?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working plnkr with solution and some extra

http://plnkr.co/edit/eOmHhR1VWjfYzHYqiEY1?p=preview

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <label><input type="text" ng-model="search.vals">vals</label>
  <label><input type="text" ng-model="search.name">name</label>
  <div ng-repeat="i in filteredArr = (iArr | filter:search)">{{i.vals}} | {{i.name}}</div>
  <div ng-if="!filteredArr.length">0</div>
</body>
```